# Bash Shell Scripting - Dialog form variables

Tags: bash, shell, variables, scripting

So, I just took up Shell Scripting and I'm developing an address book.

For the user to insert a contact I made this form:

```
form=$(dialog                                      \
    --title "INSERIR"                              \
    --form  ""                                     \
    0 0 0                                          \
    "Nome:"      1 1    "$nome"     1 10 20 0      \
    "Morada:"    2 1    "$morada"   2 10 20 0      \
    "Telefone:"  3 1    "$telefone"     3 10 20 0  \
    "E-Mail:"    4 1    "$mail"     4 10 20 0      \  
2>&1 1>&3)
```

And I want to insert those values through a MySQL query. I saw somewhere that I had to use, for instance:

```
form[$1]
```

In order to access the variable $nome. However, it was a comment from 2008.
What is the easiest way to access those variables?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the output from that `dialog` command? The `form` variable will contain that exact output (with trailing whitespace removed) as a string (not an array). So the `${form[1]}`/etc. array indexing syntax is incorrect here.

Comment: Well, actually it does output all the variables in a single string with [] at the end.

Comment: Show the output please.

Comment: For example:
    Ricardo
    Boulevard Avenue
    +35191256835
    loremipsum@gmail.com[]

Comment: It seems, from the documentation, that the output is newline separated which means you need to read the output by-line and not just stuff it all into a variable.

Comment: One can also use the [`--output-separator`](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/manpage/dialog.html#h3-Common-Options) option, to get something other than newlines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' nome morada telefone mail < <( dialog ... )
```

Unlike `dialog ... | { read; ... }` (which scopes the variables which are read to a subshell), this approach puts dialog in the subshell, and your variables in the main shell -- much more convenient.

Answer (score 2):

So, after a bit of tinkering I got what I was looking for. 
Here is the new form:

```
exec 3>&1

dialog                                             \
--separate-widget $'\n'                            \
--title "INSERIR"                                  \
--form ""                                          \
0 0 0                                              \
"Nome:"     1 1 "$nome"     1 10 30 0              \
"Morada:"       2 1     "$morada"       2 10 30 0  \
"Telefone:"     3 1     "$telefone" 3 10 30 0      \
"E-Mail:"       4 1     "$mail"         4 10 30 0  \
2>&1 1>&3 | {
    read -r nome
    read -r morada
    read -r telefone
    read -r mail

    #The rest of the script goes here
}

exec 3>&-
```

Comment: That runs "the rest of your script" in a subshell -- works in this specific use case, but in a great many situations it won't (what if you're trying to do the dialog call in a function, and want to be able to return)?

Answer (score 2):

So, you can really just put the output into an array and deal with that. Avoids all the subshell / subprocess garbage. (Just trust on the flippy redirect, yeah, it's ugly but you're basically just subbing out stdin and swapping it back.) Not sure why that's been so elusive after 5 years, but hey. I guess it's cool to be obscure.

```
response=$(dialog                                  \
    --title "INSERIR"                              \
    --form  ""                                     \
    0 0 0                                          \
    "Nome:"      1 1    "$nome"     1 10 20 0      \
    "Morada:"    2 1    "$morada"   2 10 20 0      \
    "Telefone:"  3 1    "$telefone"     3 10 20 0  \
    "E-Mail:"    4 1    "$mail"     4 10 20 0      \  
    3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&-)

#convert the space separated string to an array.. the madness!!
responsearray=($response)

echo ${responsearray[0]} #nome
echo $(responsearray[1]} #morada
echo ${responsearray[2]} #telefone
echo ${responsearray[3]} #mail
```

...and bob's your uncle.

Answer (score 1):

After several days looking for a way get those variables, here what I used, with your form:

```
nome=""
morada=""
telefone=""
mail=""

user_record=$(\
dialog                                             \
--separate-widget $'\n'                            \
--title "INSERIR"                                  \
--form ""                                          \
0 0 0                                              \
"Nome:"     1 1 "$nome"     1 10 30 0              \
"Morada:"       2 1     "$morada"       2 10 30 0  \
"Telefone:"     3 1     "$telefone" 3 10 30 0      \
"E-Mail:"       4 1     "$mail"         4 10 30 0  \
  3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&- \
)
nome=$(echo "$user_record" | sed -n 1p)
morada=$(echo "$user_record" | sed -n 2p)
telefone=$(echo "$user_record" | sed -n 3p)
mail=$(echo "$user_record" | sed -n 4p)

echo $nome
echo $morada
echo $telefone
echo $mail
```

This way you can use those variables later on your script.
Hope it helps others.

Answer (score 0):

The question regarding the easiest way to access the result depends partly on whether the items might contain blanks.  If the items can contain arbitrary data, then line-oriented output (the default) seems the only way to go.  If they are more constrained, e.g., not containing some readily-used punctuation character which can be used as a delimiter, then that makes it simpler.

The [manual page](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/manpage/dialog.html#h3-Common-Options) mentions an option (and alias) which can be used to do this:

> `--separator` *string*
>
> `--output-separator` *string*
>
> Specify  a string that will separate the output on dialog's output from checklists, rather than a newline (for  `--separate-output`)  or  a  space.  This applies to other widgets such as **forms**
> and **editboxes** which normally use a newline.

For example, if the data does not include a `:` (colon), then you could use the option

```
--output-separator :
```

and get colon-separated values on a single line.

If there are no commas or quotes in the string, you could conceivably use

```
--output-separator \",\"
```

and embed the result directly in an SQL statement.  However, commas occur more frequently than the other punctuation mentioned, so processing the form's output with `sed` is the most likely way one might proceed.

Comment: great idea for vulnerability